# Error: No resource with given URL found, 500 (Internal Server Error) asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente código el cual envía un array con los datos de mi tabla HTML al controlador para actualizarlos en la base de datos hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que muestra el error: Error: No resource with given URL found, 500 (Internal Server Error) asp.net mvc

Aclaro que ambas funciones (ajax y la de del controlador) se repiten por cada fila de mi tabla.

```html
        function GuardarF() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/MyController/MyView',
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                  array: array
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.rstProceso === "true") {
                    console.log('Exito: ' + data.rstMensaje);
                } else if (data.rstProceso === "false") {
                    console.log('Algo salió mal ' + data.rstMensaje);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, err){
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

MyController

```html
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(int[] array)
{
  JsonResult dtaEjecucionTarea = default(JsonResult);
        dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new
        {
            rstProceso = "false",
            MessageGestion = "Error, algo salió mal, intente de nuevo"
        });

        if (Update_MyView(array))
        {
            dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new
            {
                rstProceso = "true",
                MessageGestion = "Cambios guardados con éxito"
            });
        }
  return View(dtaEjecucionTarea);
}

public bool Update_MyView(int[] array)
{
   if (array != null)
   {
    //my code
    bd.SaveChanges();
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ejemplificar el error que tienes o poner alguna imagen para entender mejor lo que estás queriendo hacer? Se me disparan muchas dudas al querer ayudarte.

Comment: Declaras _columna3, pero en el switch llevas columna3, ¿ podrías revisar eso por un lado ?

Comment: Estas recibiendo algo en el `int[] array` de la Acción MyView??.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta si, si se estan recibiendo los datos, el problema es que nose como guardar los elementos del array en mi base de datos ya que se va a repetir fila por fila

Comment: @EduBw listo fue un error al copiar

Comment: @EduBw Recorre el array con un for o foreach y lo vas insertando en tu base de datos, puedes crear un modelo para almacenar los items del array y ir guardando

Comment: @Huntzberger Ok, pues indica cómo los quieres guardar, si utilizas algún ORM (Entity Framework), en que tabla de la BD vas a guardar los datos (Modelo de datos), etc.

Comment: ¿Sería mucho pedir que edites nuevamente la pregunta colocando un ejemplo de edición y visualización de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: @fredyfx ya lo edite nuevamente, espero ser mas claro

Comment: Sigo sin entender, ¿quieres sobre escribir los datos? ¿hay reglas de negocio que esté obviando? ¿y si le pones un ID que se entienda a cada ubicación como `semana36semanas37`, inclusive podrías guardar como lista de objetos: id, valor donde el ID sea el mencionado en este ejemplo `semana36semanas37`?

Comment: @fredyfx ya actualice mi pregunta

Comment: Mencionas un error pero qué error es el que te sale, en tu ajax, en la función de error puedes cambiarlo por `error: function (err) { console.error(err); console.log('algo salió mal'); }` y poner qué error es el que muestra antes de 'algo salió mal'?.

Comment: @Vlady sale: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}   error: No resource with given URL found

Comment: no mano, no... La pregunta original ya valió, esto va a seguir mutando, deja la pregunta original, si esa pudiste resolver, agrega la respuesta, luego crea una nueva pregunta. Colabora con el orden del sitio por favor :D PD: Son 14 (catorce) Ediciones...

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @fredyfx, la pregunta original no tiene ninguna relación con la pregunta actual, deberías formular nuevas preguntas cada vez y no modificar una existente. Sobre el error 500, deberías poner un punto de depuración y ver dónde muere el código, o mejor, utilizar `try` `catch` y revisar la excepción que lance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por mi parte recomendaría que la función MyView, retorne un JSon, con información afirmativa o negativa de ejecución de la tarea, con la finalidad que la función success de JQuery-Ajax obtenga esa información y la procese, p.e.:

```
--
--  JavaScript
--

function Guardar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/MyController/MyView',
        traditional: true,
        data: {
              array: array
        },
        success: function ( data ) {
          if (data.rstProceso === "true") {
            console.log( 'Exito: '+ data.rstMensaje );
          }else if(data.rstProceso === "false"){
            console.log( 'Algo salió mal '+ data.rstMensaje );
          }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('algo salió mal');
        }
    });
}



--
--  ASP - MVC
--

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyView(int[] array)
{
  JsonResult dtaEjecucionTarea = default(JsonResult);
  dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new{
      rstProceso = "false",
      MessageGestion = "Error, algo salió mal, intente de nuevo"
  });

  if( Update_MyView(array) )
  {
    dtaEjecucionTarea = Json(new{
      rstProceso = "true",
      MessageGestion = "Cambios guardados con éxito"
    });
  }

  return dtaEjecucionTarea  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A mi me pasaba algo similar solo que no carga ninguna img o archivo .js 
en un proyecto de asp en c# cuando cambiaba el puerto de la aplicación
demore un día en encontrar el error
lo pille en web.config comente el codigo y se arreglo

```
<!--
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
-->
```